# Causation doesn't imply correlation and correlation does not imply causation

Tags: logic

Let P := |corr($X,Y$) > .5|
let Q := exits a relation F:$X\implies Y$

Then the often stated line of correlation does not imply causation is simply !($P \implies Q$).

It is also true that causation does not imply correlation. So !($Q \implies P$)

But $(P\implies Q) \lor (Q\implies P)$ is a tautology.

I know I am not seeing clearly, but I don't see it.

Sorry if this is answered, I didn't see and also sorry if this is too simplistic. I just don't get where my thinking is off.

Thanks

Comment: If two events have a causal relationship, they are necessarily correlated. Where have you seen otherwise? Correlation does not imply causation is a true statement, but causation always implies correlation.

Comment: There are tons of examples of nonlinear causal relationships that have near zero correlation. Feel free to google or ill post specific examples if necessary.

Comment: I should add that I specifically mean linear correlation.     https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence

Comment: @InterstellarProbe: Causation does imply mutual information, but not correlation.

Answer (score 4):

Your $P$ and $Q$ are not propositions; they  are predicates.  That is, the truth value of $P$ varies depending on $X$ and $Y$.

The correct translation of "Correlation does not imply causation" is not $!(P\rightarrow Q)$.  Instead it is

$$!((\forall X,Y)( P(X,Y)\rightarrow Q(X,Y))$$

Given this, you'll find that you can't formulate your paradox.

Note, incidentally, that the key issue here has nothing to do with correlation and causation.  You could take statement "P" to be "Chris is a women" and "Q" to be "Chris is a parent".  If we allow for the fact that there are many people named Chris in the world, these statements are predicates with truth values that depend on which Chris you're talking about.

Now it is not true that "All women are parents" and it is not true that "All parents are women", so if your logic were correct, you could apply it here equally well and get the same paradox without ever mentioning causation  or correlation.  The resolution remains the same.

Comment: I realized there was quantification happening, and I should have written it all out. But in my head I was using the existential quantifier rather than the universal.

In my head I was having the following conversation:
It is true that for some sets, X and Y  correlation doesn't imply causation and causation doesn't imply correlation. 

But When we casually say, "correlation does not imply causation", we really mean that with the universal quantifier. 

Thanks for helping to think though this Asura Path.

Comment: @JeremyBall : It sounds like you're on top of this now, so you probably don't need this further explanation but:  "All women are parents" is identical in meaning to "If Chris is a woman then Chris  is a parent" --- one thing to keep in mind if you want to formalize all this.